# What's the right HTTP error code if parsing the request fails

Tags: parsing, http, http-headers, http-error

If you create a web service which receives an processes some data like `XML`/`JSON` and the parsing of the data fails because it's incorrect, what do you do?

- Send a HTTP 400 error code: After all it was the client who messed up the data (`XML`/`JSON`)
- Send a HTTP 500 error code: It's the server who wasn't able to complete its task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If data in the request is malformed, then you'll want to return a 400 level error. Generally 500-level errors mean that something is wrong on the server that has nothing to do with the client or the client's request.

Comment: Specifically, "400 Bad Request" http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc72311#section-6.5.1

Answer (score 2):

422 code.

> 422 Unprocessable Entity
>
> The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server
> understands the content type of the request entity (hence a
> 415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the
> syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request)
> status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained
> instructions.  For example, this error condition may occur if an XML
> request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but
> semantically erroneous, XML instructions

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11